# Avocado Tree seed shirnking?

Tags: houseplants, seedlings, avocado

I have four avocado tree seedlings (started growing them in mid-2020) One of the seeds split in two and it grew into two trees. One of the half seed trees' seed is shriveling, unlike its twin. I noticed the leaves are drooping as well, everything is green with no noticeable brown on the leaves. I gave it a little citrus food and now buying some anti-fungal spray to help prevent root rot. I replanted the avocado seedling in drier soil and used some of the wet soil as a base and some on the top.

Does anyone have any other advice to help?

Comment: can you add a picture?